# Why DeviceId is require when checking for license

Tags: java, android

I've read many pages of documentation of android licensing but I'm still confuse. Why does it need unique device id when it checks with primary account logged into the device ?

and if it needs for something, what if that unique id changes somehow ? Will it still allow same user ? if yes, then whats the point of unique id and if no, then its bad, what if user had to factory reset and that changes its device id.

Comment: good question, a valid point `what if user had to factory reset and that changes its device id.`